(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
I'm trying to connect MySQL database to Vanna Ai using
vn.connect_to_mysql(host='localhost', dbname='db_creation_atliq_t_shirts', user='root', password='root', port=3306)
I'm getting this error: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
Code
